# Porque no puedo volver a añadir una clase con classList.add()

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objeto

Veran estoy intentando hacer una especie de piano donde tu le pasas las notas en un arreglo y el piano las ira tocando conforme lo indique, la idea es que se cuche la melodía al mismo tiempo que se van coloreando las teclas que se tocan, ya casi tengo la parte de colorear las teclas pero hay un pequeño detalle, estoy usando classList.add y classList.remove para agregar y remover el color respectivamente por medio de una clase css, les pongo el ejemplo de lo que me pasa:
Primero se tocan 2 teclas fa en diferente frecuencia, despues se debe tocar una tecla fa de las anteriores con otra distinta, en las 2 primeras teclas fa todo va bien, se añade y desaparece la clase correctamente, pero cuando quiero pasar a la segunda ronda de notas la clase 'active' no se añade a mi tecla fa y en la tercera ronda de teclas pasa algo parecido, les dejo mi codigo:

```
const reproducirRola = document.getElementById('comenzar');


class teclas {
    constructor(nota) {
        this.tecla = document.getElementById(`${nota}`);

    }
}

class cancion {
    constructor() {
        this.empezar();
    }

    empezar() {
        let comenzar = document.getElementById('comenzar');
        comenzar.addEventListener('click', this.tocarIntro());
    }

    tocarIntro() {
        let contador = 0;
        for (let elemento in intro) {
            contador++;
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.iluminarTeclas(intro[elemento][0], intro[elemento][1])
                console.log(intro[elemento][0]);
                console.log(intro[elemento][1])
            }, 1000 * contador);
        }

    }


    iluminarTeclas(nota1, nota2) {
        const tecla1 = nota1;
        const tecla2 = nota2;
        tecla1.classList.add('active');
        tecla2.classList.add('active');

        setTimeout(() => {
            tecla1.classList.remove('active')
            tecla2.classList.remove('active')
            console.log(tecla1)
            console.log(tecla2)

        }, 1000)
    }
}

escala2 = {
    do: new teclas("do1"),
    re: new teclas("re1"),
    mi: new teclas("mi1"),
    fa: new teclas("fa1"),
    sol: new teclas("sol1"),
    la: new teclas("la1"),
    si: new teclas("si1"),
}
escala3 = {
    do: new teclas("do2"),
    re: new teclas("re2"),
    mi: new teclas("mi2"),
    fa: new teclas("fa2"),
    sol: new teclas("sol2"),
    la: new teclas("la2"),
    si: new teclas("si2"),

}

escala4 = {
    do: new teclas("do3"),
    re: new teclas("re3"),
    mi: new teclas("mi3"),
    fa: new teclas("fa3"),
    sol: new teclas("sol3"),
    la: new teclas("la3"),
    si: new teclas("si3"),

}

escala5 = {
    do: new teclas("do4"),
    re: new teclas("re4"),
    mi: new teclas("mi4"),
    fa: new teclas("fa4"),
}

Bemoles1 = {
    do: new teclas("doB1"),
    re: new teclas("reB1"),
    fa: new teclas("faB1"),
    sol: new teclas("solB1"),
    la: new teclas("laB1")
}

Bemoles2 = {
    do: new teclas("doB2"),
    re: new teclas("reB2"),
    fa: new teclas("faB2"),
    sol: new teclas("solB2"),
    la: new teclas("laB2")
}

Bemoles3 = {
    do: new teclas("doB3"),
    re: new teclas("reB3"),
    fa: new teclas("faB3"),
    sol: new teclas("solB3"),
    la: new teclas("laB3")
}

Bemoles4 = {
    do: new teclas("doB4"),
    re: new teclas("reB4"),
    fa: new teclas("faB4"),
}

intro = {
    parte1: [escala2.fa.tecla, escala3.fa.tecla],
    paerte2: [Bemoles1.la.tecla, escala3.fa.tecla],
    parte3: [Bemoles1.sol.tecla, escala3.fa.tecla],
    parte4: [Bemoles1.re.tecla, Bemoles2.re.tecla]

}

reproducirRola.addEventListener('click', reproducirCancion);

function reproducirCancion() {
    window.cancion = new cancion()
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver en la imagen la tecla con id="fa2" se añade
la clase active sin problemas, despues en el codigo se elemina, pero posteriormente se le indica que se añada otra vez y esto no sucede. ¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de porque sucede esto?

Comment: Revisaste si aparecen errores en la consola cuando haces clic o en otro momento?

Comment: De echo no se deben iluminar cuando hago click, solo se iran iluminando conforme yo le valla pasando los parametros a mi funcion iluminar teclas, en si es como si le pasara la cancion ya escrita y la fuera tocando pro si solo.

Comment: Tienes razon. Peude ser un problema de sincronizacion y evaluacion de logs. Podrias cambiar el segundo setTimeout() a un valor menor a 1000 para ver si es eso (ejemplo: 900)

Answer (score 1):

el problema no es que no se pueda agregar o quitar la clase, lo que sucede es que por los multiplicadores que usas en el timeout sucede que al mismo tiempo que se agrega se esta quitando, una sugerencia es colocar un pequeno desfase de 50 ms en tu funcion iluminarTeclas

es decir:

```
    iluminarTeclas(nota1, nota2) {
    const tecla1 = nota1;
    const tecla2 = nota2;
    tecla1.classList.add('active');
    tecla2.classList.add('active');

    setTimeout(() => {
        tecla1.classList.remove('active')
        tecla2.classList.remove('active')
        console.log(tecla1)
        console.log(tecla2)

    }, 950) // AQUI LO CAMBIAMOS PARA QUE NO SE EMPALME CON LA FUNCION ANTERIOR
}
```

[Ejemplo en codepen](https://codepen.io/overvoiplatam/pen/jOqWQYW)

Comment: O ya veo, excelente amigo, gracias por tu aporte, no lo habia tomado en cuenta.

Comment: Excelente, si esto soluciona tu problema no olvides colocar como respondida la pregunta. saludos